# How can I put values from one numpy array into another at indices specified by a third array (bonus, the indices are floats)

Tags: python, numpy

I have written code that extracts a portion of an image and saves it as a second image along with an array that maps each pixel in the new image to it's original position. The new image is not a rectangular crop from the original image and is not something that can undergo a simple transform back to the original shape.
example:

```
new_img = np.zeros((5,5,3))
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
poorly_shaped_img = np.random.random((3,2,3))
array([[[0.56996145, 0.66969092, 0.39299133],
        [0.71405233, 0.81291533, 0.84920548]],
       [[0.75519416, 0.25214197, 0.45477072],
        [0.05180197, 0.64204567, 0.81518423]],
       [[0.91130947, 0.69654691, 0.99531231],
        [0.07430683, 0.18580811, 0.66368306]]])
rounded_pixel_map:
array([[[0,0],[0,2]],
       [[1,4],[2,4]],
       [[0,3],[4,2]]])
desired_output:
array([[[0.56996145, 0.66969092, 0.39299133],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0.71405233, 0.81291533, 0.84920548],
        [0.91130947, 0.69654691, 0.99531231],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0.75519416, 0.25214197, 0.45477072]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0.05180197, 0.64204567, 0.81518423]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],
       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0.07430683, 0.18580811, 0.66368306],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Is there any way to put these values back where they belong without looping over them?
If I were to loop over it would look something like this:

```
for i in range(len(rounded_pixel_map)):
    for j in range(len(rounded_pixel_map[i])):
        pixel_coords = rounded_pixel_map[i][j]
        pixel_value = poorly_shaped_img[i][j]
        new_img[pixel_coords[0], pixel_coords[1]] = pixel_value
```

Even this is only one portion of the true problem. In generating this "poorly shaped image" I used bilinear interpolation because I often needed values for non-integer pixels. The pixel map array is full of floats so I would also need a way to "reverse interpolate" to get the correct values at the integer indices.

The problem with that loop option is performance. These poorly shaped images are 4096 x 80 pixels so looping in this way is not performant at all. And I don't know how to apply the "reverse interpolation" to go from float indices to the proper values at integer indices.

Answer (score 0):

One way is

```py
idx=rounded_pixel_map.reshape(-1,2)
new_img[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]] = poorly_shaped_img.reshape(-1,3)
```

Explanation: I don't really need to care about the shape of index. The point is, if I read all of them in order (in C order namely, but it doesn't really matter, as long as reshape does the same thing to both `index` and `poorly_shaped_array`), the I must store them in these places.

So it is just a matter of flattening both index and source image.  Except that we want the flattening of the index to keeps an array of coordinates (so pairs), and we want the flattening of the image to keeps pixels (so tripled). So flattening all but last, size 2 axis, is `reshape(-1,2)`, and flattening all but last, size 3, axis, is `reshape(-1,3)`

Comment: This solution works well! Now to figure out the best way to handle those pesky non-integer index values

Comment: I haven't seen the non-integer you are mentionning. But if they are just integers that happens to be encoded in floats, then I don't think there is anything more subtle that `.round().astype(np.int32)` to do. So `idx=pixel_map.reshape(-1,2).round().astype(np.int32)`

Comment: I didn't explicitly include them in the example since rounding is a "close enough" solution that should work 80% of the time for my use-case. In truth the pixel_map has many values that are intentionally non-integers like [3.707, 1.2] to represent values taken from the original image by bilinear interpolation at that point. I don't know of any good way to "undo" said interpolation so I'm opting to just round to the nearest integer.

Comment: The only alternative, depending on what are your data, could be to say that `[3.707, 1.2]` means that x is 29.3% 3 and 70.7% 4, and y is 80% 1  and 20% 2. So, all together, 23.44% (3,1) 5,86% (3,2), 56,56% (4,1) and 14,14% (4,2)

Comment: And then to distribute the 3 rgb values from the source image, among the 4 positions in the target image, according to this distribution

Comment: Depending on whether it makes sense or not for your application. But if splitting rgb values between several pixels in target image doesn't make sense, then, you have to choose a target coordinates. And (4,1) is not ideal to replace (3.707, 1.2). But all other choices are worse. So, that is the only reasonnable choice if you have to make one

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid explicit loops and improve performance, you can utilize NumPy's advanced indexing and broadcasting capabilities to achieve your desired result. Here's how you can modify your code to avoid looping:

```
import numpy as np

new_img = np.zeros((5, 5, 3))
poorly_shaped_img = np.random.random((3, 2, 3))
rounded_pixel_map = np.array([[[0, 0], [0, 2]],
                              [[1, 4], [2, 4]],
                              [[0, 3], [4, 2]]])

# Reshape rounded_pixel_map to match the dimensions of poorly_shaped_img
reshaped_map = rounded_pixel_map[:, :, np.newaxis, :]

# Index new_img using reshaped_map to assign pixel values
new_img[reshaped_map[:, :, :, 0], reshaped_map[:, :, :, 1]] = poorly_shaped_img

print(new_img)
```